# Share Outlook task manager custom view with user defined columns

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I have created a task manager view in Microsoft Outlook which contains user defined fields as well as other Pre-defined fields in the view. I am trying to share this task manager with the rest of my team however, I cannot get it to show all of the columns as they appear on my screen on their screens. I am able to share the task manager but many of the columns are missing. It seems to be because the custom view I created isn't being shared with the other users. On my computer, the custom view is displayed and selected above "Simple list" under the Current View menu on the left and the others do no seem to have that as an option. Does anyone know how I can share the view? The tasks are already being shared I just need the View to be shared so my team can see all the columns properly. Thanks for any input you may have to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok essentially what I did was I went to view - current view - define views and created a new view selecting Table and This folder, visible to everyone. Then I found pre-definied columns that weren't user defined columns that allowed free text typing like subject, milage, and billing information. Once finished adding all the columns I needed I applied the view. Then I went and changed the name of the columns by right clicking each column header in the task manager and selecting format column. there you chan change the label name to whatever you want the column to be titled. This way you did not have to worry with using user defined columns that can be tricky to share. After that I went back to view - current view - define views, and made a copy of the view I created selecting this folder, visible to everyone.  Then you will want to right on the tasks manager name you created under the My Tasks list and select properties. Make sure to give everyone your sharing it with full permissions as owners so that they can all edit the task manager as they finish each task. Then I shared this task manager by right clicking on the name of my newly created tasks manager (listed under the My Tasks menu) and selecting "share". I checked the box in the email stating recipient can add, edit, and delete items in this tasks folder.  Now everyone can see all information displayed in each column and edit it as well hope this helps.